# Не работает условие скрипта jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Суть заключается в том, что если в input с id="nameReg" прописать 1, то будет выскакивать alert, но ничего не происходит.
Полагаю ошибка в присвоении переменных.

*html:*

```
<form action="" method="post" name="RegForm">
  <hr class="regHR"><div id="textReg">Для обладания полными пользовательскими правами пройдите регистрацию.</div></br><hr class="regHR">
  <label for="nameReg">Введите желаемый логин:</label></br>
  <input type="text" name="nameReg" id="nameReg" class="log" placeholder="Ваш логин"/></br>
  <label for="mailReg">Введите вашу почту:</label></br>
  <input type="mail" name="mailReg" class="log" placeholder="exemple@mail.com"/></br>
  <label for="passwordReg">Введите желаемый пароль:</label></br>
  <input type="password" name="passwordReg" class="log" placeholder="********"/></br>
  <label for="passwordReg2">Повторите ввод пароля:</label></br>
  <input type="password" name="passwordReg2" class="log" placeholder="********"/></br>
  <input type="submit" name="sumbitReg-button" id="submitReg-button" value="Зарегистрировать"/></br>
</form>
```

*Jquery:*

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#submitReg-button').click(function (){
    var nameReg = form.nameReg.value;
    if(nameReg == "1"){
      alert("Введённые вами данные не корректны");
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: откуда у вас в коде взялся объект form?

Comment: Предполагалось,что это будет форма регистрации

Comment: Это здорово, а откуда этот объект возьмется? Где в коде `var form = smth`?

Comment: Честно говоря,я не натыкался в процессе обучение ещё на то,что так надо прописывать и для чего это вообще требуется,я думал,что form просто указывает,что это форма и более ничего не требуется

Comment: представьте, что на сайте 5 форм. На что этот объект будет ссылаться? Объект всегда объявляется (если это не window и не document, конечно) в переменной

Comment: То-есть нужно было дать конкретный id форме,чтобы опираться конкретно на неё,я правильно понял?

Comment: как вариант - да. Можно обращаться и по `name`. Т.е. `var form = $('[name="RegForm"]')`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,понял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задание, то получается если вводим один, видим alert, если нет, то не видим:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitReg-button').click(function() {
    var value = $(".pole").val();
    if (value === '1') {
      alert("Введённые вами данные не корректны");
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" name="RegForm">
  <hr class="regHR">
  <div id="textReg">Для обладания полными пользовательскими правами пройдите регистрацию.</div>
  <br>
  <hr class="regHR">
  <label for="nameReg">Введите желаемый логин:</label><br>
  <input class="pole" type="text" name="nameReg" id="nameReg" class="log" placeholder="Ваш логин" /><br>
  <label for="mailReg">Введите вашу почту:</label><br>
  <input type="mail" name="mailReg" class="log" placeholder="exemple@mail.com" /><br>
  <label for="passwordReg">Введите желаемый пароль:</label><br>
  <input type="password" name="passwordReg" class="log" placeholder="********" /><br>
  <label for="passwordReg2">Повторите ввод пароля:</label><br>
  <input type="password" name="passwordReg2" class="log" placeholder="********" /><br>
  <input type="submit" name="sumbitReg-button" id="submitReg-button" value="Зарегистрировать" /><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Заменить

```
var nameReg = form.nameReg.value;
```

на

```
var nameReg = $("#nameReg").val();
```